# Challah Loaf Tearing

Tags: baking, bread, kneading, proofing

[image]

I think the bread looks mostly okay for a first go at it, but I'm looking for any advice on the slight tearing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: IMHO, that level of tearing is completely normal.  And I make a lot of challah.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's definitely good, I'd happily have a piece of your Challah.

It looks to me like you under-proofed your dough after you braided it, what you are seeing is a lot of oven spring in action. Next time give it a bit more time before baking. Also, maybe you could braid it a bit more loosely, if it's too tight the expansion doesn't have anywhere to go.

Not related to your question, if you want a slightly lighter color dilute the egg wash with a bit of water, it makes it go on smoother as well.